How do I draw a Brownian motion inside an axis environment?
I want to draw a standard Brownian motion from time 0 to 1. Building up on this answer, I've tried the following:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots, tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\newcommand{\Emmett}[5] % color, x0, dt, n 
{
    \draw[#1] (0, #2)
    \foreach\x in {1, ..., #4} {
        -- ++(#3, rand * #3)
    }
    node[right] {#5};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line = center,
        axis y line = center,
        xtick = {0, ..., 1},
        ytick = {-1, ..., 1},
        xlabel = {$t$},
        ylabel = {$x$},
        xlabel style = {right},
        ylabel style = {above},
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 1.1,
        ymin = -1,
        ymax = 1]

        \Emmett{black}{0}{.01}{100}{};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

The output is

and hence there is obviously something wrong. I need to admit that I don't fully understand the \Emmett macro and most probably something is wrong with it. What the code should actually do is the following:
t = 0;
x = x0;

for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    plot (t, x);

    let xi be a sample from the standard normal distribution;
    x += sqrt(dt) * xi;
}

So, how do I need to adjust the macro? A path of the standard Brownian motion should actually look like


The problem is that you are mixing things up:

yes, pgfplots is built on Tikz,
and yes, you can add Tikz-things to a pgfplot, like labels
but no: it follows its own rules and syntax to display ... data
in other words: you can't mix it the way you tried (or it will be lots of unecessary work for adaptation)

So here is an example with pgfplots, where you don't need a macro like \Emmett, and below it a pure Tikz apporach with said macro.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots, tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\newcommand{\Emmett}[5] % color, x0, dt, n 
{
    \draw[#1] (0, #2)
    \foreach\x in {1, ..., #4} {
        -- ++(#3, rand * #3)
    };
%    node[right] {#5}; % seems to be ... for trash
}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

% ~~~ using pgfplots features ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}%[>=latex]
    \begin{axis}[
            title= Random data,
            xlabel=events,
            ylabel=whateverItIs,
        ]
        \addplot[
            domain=0:100,   
        ]{3*rand};  
    \end{axis}

 \end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{8mm}

 % ~~~ using Tikz ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[<->]  (0,1)node[anchor=south]{y} -- 
                (0,0) -- (10,0)node[anchor=west]{x};
    \Emmett{red}{0}{.1}{100};   %{X};
 \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}


Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, neither of your suggested solutions does what I would like to achieve: Drawing a path of a Brownian motion on $[0,1]$. Your tikz solution, using the \Emmett macro, should be a Brownian motion on $[0,10]$, but the plot doesn't look like that. I think something in that macro is wrong and it is not following the pseudocode I provided in my question. How can we fix it?

I would also be happy to use use your pgfplots solution, but how would be sample a Brownian motion path with that? You only sample some "random data".

BTW: What exactly is rand? Is it a sample from the standard normal distribution?

As in any other language rand denotes a uniform distribution. To mimick normal, just add a few calls of rand, which converges to normal as n->infty.

Please rework your question to make your objective crystall clear. Comments will exhaust for that quite soon ... and it's better to read a well written question than hunting through an ocean of comments ;-)

It actually seems like rand is uniform on [-1, 1], while rnd is uniform on [0, 1], which is what is usually called rand in any other language.

Bye. //  Both intervals are related by a simple transformation. // 2nd call: caomments aren't made for discussions. Move to a dedicated chatroom for that. Bye
